# How to disable error reporting in PHP (nginx)

Tags: php

This is not the first time someone asks this question, but I went through all the similar cases I found and could not resolve this issue.

I am running a local development environment, with PHP-FPM 7.4 using NGINX.

I added `error_reporting(0);` at the top of my PHP.

I added `display_errors = Off` to the php.ini file at **/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini** - because that is the actual php.ini file being loaded by PHP, as per *phpinfo()*

[image]

I reloaded the PHP service and the NGINX server.

> sudo service php7.4-fpm reload
> sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload

But still warnings are being displayed on screen.

I know that just hidding errors is not a way to fix them, but I am doing quick changes to an old project and I don't want to make it work perfect, just fix some stuff and keep going.

Also I searched for `error_reporting` and `ini_set` strings in the entire project folder and didn't find anything.

**phpinfo() output for error_reporting**:

[image]

As Silbee said in the comments, the numeric value is a mask for E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED.

What can I do to find out where that value is being set?

Comment: have you checked error reporting level with phpinfo() ? Also, php fpm allows ini overriding per pool, check your fpm/pool.d/ for conf files.

Comment: @Silbee Thanks for your attention. phpinfo() says: `error_reporting` = 22527 (both for local and master value). I don't understand what that might mean.

Comment: That value is a bitmap mask. In this case, 22527 is a mask for E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED .. so php is displaying all errors except deprecated

Comment: @Silbee Thanks for the explanation, that helps. And do you know what could be the potential reason of why PHP is "ignoring" the `display_errors = Off` value in the php.ini?

Comment: Is there a files called /your_php_fpm_path/fpm-conf.php ? Or any files in /your_php_fpm_path/pool.d ? Look for 'php_flag[display_errors]' as that can override the ini.

Comment: There actually was a file inside the fpool.d folder called www.conf. And with a value 'php_flag_admin[display_errors]. Now working great. Thanks for your amazing help.

Comment: If you were able to resolve the issue with the help, please don't hesitate to [answer it](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) as well. You're the one who knows the step-by-step how-to, so you're the best person to write one too :-) Please make sure the answer follows the guideline for [writing a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and stop by after 48 hours to accept your answer. This will make it useful for others in the future.